# What type of filter is this?

Tags: filters, filter-design, filtering, highpass-filter, adaptive-filters

```
float xx = acceleration.x;
float yy = acceleration.y;
float zz = acceleration.z;

float dot = (px * xx) + (py * yy) + (pz * zz);
float a = ABS(sqrt(px * px + py * py + pz * pz));
float b = ABS(sqrt(xx * xx + yy * yy + zz * zz));

dot /= (a * b);
```

I run into the equation above on [github](https://github.com/pdetagyos/Pedometer/blob/master/Pedometer/ViewController.m), but I don't know what kind of DSP filter is this?

$$ result= \frac{x_{prev} * x + y_{prev} * y + z_{prev} * z }{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} * \sqrt{(x_{prev}^2 + y_{prev}^2 + z_{prev}^2)}} $$

If my question is too obvious please forgive my ignorance, I hope that it is a real question and it not will be closed.

Comment: It looks like $corr(a, a_{prev})=cos\theta=\frac{a \cdot a_{prev}}{\|a\|\|a_{prev}\|}$, where vectors $a=\{x, y, z\}$,  $a_{prev}=\{x_{prev}, y_{prev}, z_{prev}\}$ and $\theta$ is the angle between them (see [Pearson product-moment correlation coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient#Geometric_interpretation)). But surely my interpretation is not like a filter...

Comment: werediver: Looks right, should calculate the cosine of the angle between the previous and current measurement.